# GWT Server side RPC classes not found

Tags: gwt

I am developing a GWT application using maven modules and the structure is as below

ServerModule - contains server side code
ClientModule - contains client side gwt code and rpc code
         com.test.client - gwt classes
         com.test.server - rpc classes

I want to deploy the war file into jboss server
I am building the client module using maven:war plugin it compiles without any errors but
I could not find any class files for the server side classes I have under server package.

Can you please explain me how I can build the server side classes and when it will generate class files ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please publish relevant folder layout and maven pom.xml for clarity in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try understanding from GWT sample pom files.

Validation example - https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/validation/pom.xml

MobileWebApp Example - https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp/pom.xml

DynaTable Example - https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/dynatablerf/pom.xml

**Sample target directory for mobilewebapp -**

[image]

Comment: I am using maven plugin instead of resources plugin
<plugin><groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId><artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId><version>${gwt.version}</version><executions>
<execution><goals><goal>compile</goal></goals></execution></executions>

Comment: Check the above samples. They all use the gwt-maven-plugin :)

Comment: If I include the above resources, it is including only the java files into the webappDirectory.Instead How can I get the class files included ?

Comment: Will update the process after tryin a build on mobilewebapp. You can download mobilewebapp from https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-2.5.1.zip

Comment: After I have replaced maven war plugin with maven resources, it's generating class files. But Now another problem raise up. I have a another maven module called server to implement the hibernate layer and added this module as dependency to client module but the classes from the server module is not being referred in GWT hosted mode. If I deploy the war file generated into jboss it's working fine. Can you please give me some insights why this is breaking when running from eclipse ?

Comment: I have found the problem, its not because of the dependency modules.Actually it's due to the dependency hibernate jars it's referring internally.I have made the scope as provided since it is available in the server, after I removed the scope its adding the dependencies locally and started running from eclipse. Thanks for all your response.